# Android RecyclerView album like

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I wish to achieve an android design which like the image below
[Joox Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWfME.jpg)

which the recyclerview able to scroll horizontally and some icon and text view in the album cover plus title under the album cover. This can be achieve by using card view or any other layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set recyclerview layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) and use cardView for item